# Inconsistent scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have downloaded the "about section" for some facebook pages using request.get and have been scraping off the coordinates from the mini-map on the page using the following code:

```
html = open(file, "r",encoding='utf-8').read()        # Opening saved html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')              # Parsing html

map_url = soup.find_all(class_='_a3f img')            # Extracting url of map

parsed =urlparse.urlparse(map_url['src'])             # Extracting url parameters
coordinate_marker = parse_qs(parsed.query)['markers'] # Return coordinates
```

This has worked well, apart from a few instances. In these instances, the saved html still has a map, and `'_a3f img' in str(soup)` returns True, it just isn't returning anything with 'find_all'.

What's stranger, is when I open the saved HTML in Chrome, copy and paste the entire HTML into a new file - that then runs fine and returns the coordinates (both files are the same size).

I have tried changing the parser (no luck). Any explanation for this would be greatly appreciated!